# Static Singleton?

Tags: c++, templates, static

Is it possible to make a generic singleton? I want to create something I can just inherit from and get the functionality of a singleton. I'm having trouble with using templates with static members.

Shouldn't this work?

**

UPDATED

**

Thanks for the replies so far. So now my problem is that GameEngine can't see it's own constructor. I know it's private but still.

**Singleton.h**

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
private:
    static std::shared_ptr<T> m_Instance;
public: 
    static std::shared_ptr<T> Instance();
};

template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> Singleton<T>::m_Instance = nullptr;

template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> Singleton<T>::Instance()
{
if(m_Instance == nullptr)
    m_Instance = std::make_shared<T>();

return m_Instance;
}
```

**GameEngine.h**

```
class GameEngine : public Singleton<GameEngine>
{
private:
GameEngine();

};
```

Comment: (1) Why do you think you need a singleton? (2) If you do use a singleton, why use a `shader_pointer`? It's not like the singleton will ever be destructed, so you might cut that part and just use a reference...

Comment: Why are you putting template code in a *.cpp?

Comment: Whenever you post a question about compiler errors, please include the _complete_ and _unedited_ error list. Also, please point out _where_ in the code the error is, as it can be hard or even impossible to count lines.

Comment: What about a singleton do you need? There are three *totally separate things* singletons provide, yet it tries to provide them as one package. If you shouldn't be allowed to copy your class, make it noncopyable. If instantiating your class more than once should be an error, detect that error and throw an exception (if you *can* construct more than once than why prevent it?). And if you need a globally available instance, make one. None of these implies the other two.

Comment: @GManNickG: The problem with creating singletons as global variables is that if one uses another from a different translation unit than the order they will be created is undefined, so this causes undefined behaviour.  If you use the local static variable pattern shown in my answer, than the singletons will be lazily initialized in the correct order.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: Both of those (non-local non-static variable & local static variable) implement "global variable" in my mind. In fact, a local static is how I implement my global variables, in the extraordinarily rare case I need them.

Comment: @GManNickG: A global variable is a variable thats name has global scope and has static storage duration.  A local static variable has a block local name and static storage duration.  They have different initialization guarantees.  It is not correct to call a local static variable a global variable.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: You're not adding new information, we both already know this. Take a step back into the real world where we use natural language for a minute: both of those are global in the sense that they can be accessed from any scope. That's it. That's what *I* mean by global. *How that's implemented is not part of my definition*. Get it?

Comment: @GManNickG: A local static variable can only be used from the local scope in which it is defined, it cannot be accessed from any scope - in the same way a local automatic variable cannot be accessed from any scope.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20711/discussion-between-gmannickg-and-andrew-tomazos-fathomling)

Comment: @GManNickG: You need to learn the distinction between name scope and storage duration.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: You *really* think I don't know what scope and storage duration is? You need to learn when people are talking in technical terms or in natural langauge concepts. I'm done here.

Comment: @GManNickG: Given this is a technical site perhaps you should consider using technical terms in future, especially if you don't like being corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create a singleton is as follows:

```
class GameEngine
{
public:
    static GameEngine& instance() { static GameEngine e; return e; }

private:
    GameEngine() {}
    GameEngine(const GameEngine&) = delete;
};
```

The e variable will be (thread-safely) initialized on first call to instance, and it will be destroyed on orderly process exit.  The private/deleted constructors prevent a second instance from ever being created.

Comment: Can you explain this e variable or have any good documentation on it? I'm confused as to how it is initialized.

Comment: It's called a _local static variable_.  The name of the variable is locally scoped to the block, but the storage duration is global.  It will be constructed the first time the function is called, but it remains for the rest of the program life.

Comment: And apparently theres a difference between delete constuctors and destructors?

Comment: That's a deletion of the default copy constructor, so that someone can't take a copy of the singleton.

Comment: The initialization of local static variables is described in section 6.7 of the C++ standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

Comment: GameEngine(const GameEngine&) = delete; Generates the following error:   Error 1 error C2059: syntax error : ';'

Comment: What compiler are you using?  It may be an old version.

Comment: VS2012, can it use different compilers? GCC or LLVM etc?

Comment: You need to turn the C++ 2011 support on.  It's a switch in your compilation settings I think.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see how that'd work, since there's nothing preventing you from creating more instances of `GameEngine`.

Even if it were possible (and it is) to have a generic way of creating a singleton (perhaps involving macros), I would advise against it, because **situations where you actually want singletons are rare**. Let me rephrase that... situations where you actually **really need** a singleton are rare.

Comment: I do agree that their should be few but the question was how not why.

Comment: For most programs I would agree. However, you're never going to want to run two games in the same process, so you might as well just use global variables for some things rather than passing around a pointer. It keeps things simpler, and it may just be a little faster.

Comment: @JoshElias:  The question may well have been "how" but one of the best things about StackOverflow, one of the reasons why it is so helpful to so many people, is because often when people with a lot of experience suspect that *the wrong question is being asked*, they will bring it up and ask the *right* question.

Comment: It's just that I every time I look for solutions on singletons, there's ALWAYS debate over whether or not they should be used. There doesn't seem to be a concrete answer. If there's a obviously better way to design a manager class that will be global and unique then please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @JoshElias I wasn't saying that. I'm not against singletons in some situations. What I'm saying is that if you implement a mechanism to create them automatically, you're on the wrong path. If you have a couple of singletons, there's no need for such a mechanism, you can just write them separately. If you have a lot of them, to the extent of wanting a mechanism to automise their creation, you're 99% sure on the wrong track.